# Export repository locations from STS or RAD

Tags: eclipse, svn, rad, spring-tool-suite, svn-repository

Due to recent hardware failures, I am having to set up a new workspace for STS and I have a lot of repositories to add.

I have added them all, but I am trying to find a way to export the repository locations so that in the future, anyone on my team or myself could pull them out of my network drive and just import them in. This would save me some time. It wouldn't be a lot of time I know, but it would be nice.

So far, the only thing I have found was an Eclipse option that I could select File/Export, select SVN Repositories and voila. However, using STS or RAD, I am not getting the SVN Repository option in the export options. Is that Eclipse exclusive? If so, why would it be removed for STS and RAD?

Any help pointing me in the right direction is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two different projects that can provide svn support in Eclipse: [Subversive](https://www.eclipse.org/subversive/) (from eclipse.org) and [Subclipse](http://subclipse.tigris.org/) (from tigris.org). STS includes Subclipse, but many people get Subversive when they install SVN support into a "plain" Eclipse. Subversive includes the ability to export your repositories when exporting preferences. My copy of STS, which has Subclipse 1.8.22, does *not* (like you observe). It appears that the feature was supposedly added to Subclipse a few years ago, according to [this](http://subclipse.tigris.org/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=421) and [this](http://subclipse.tigris.org/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=1520) (bug tickets for subclipse), so I'm not sure what's going on there. Maybe the version of Subclipse that STS includes is out of date... who knows.

One potential workaround would be to export Team Project Set(s) for the project groups that you want to be able to easily import. That will automatically include the repository info, but has other advantages, too. Read more about them [here](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-cvs-project-set.htm) and [here](http://www.eclipseonetips.com/2010/01/25/checkout-multiple-projects-automatically-into-your-eclipse-workspace/).

Comment: Perfect answer! Thank you for taking the time to respond.